# How to correctly sign apps in CyanogenMod?

Tags: android, android-source, jar-signing, cyanogenmod

I compiled CyanogenMod 7 from source code, then tried to install ADWLauncher on my device:

```
$ adb install -r ./out/target/product/crespo/system/app/ADWLauncher.apk
4147 KB/s (1060312 bytes in 0.249s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/ADWLauncher.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
```

Related question's answer says, that this means that package was not properly signed. But when I try to sign it - it fails, because the package is already signed.
How can I sign it correctly?

There is line

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := shared
```

in Android.mk. How can I override it with my own certificate?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you're trying to install a version of an app on top of another version that has a different signature.  Try completely uninstalling the already installed apk first, either via Android's UI or from adb:

`adb uninstall org.adw.launcher`

Then try installing fresh again.  The same error can occur even if you've built both versions yourself- say first having installed a version signed with a release key, and then installing the same app again using test/debug keys.